# What happens if an exception is thrown from a function which was called inside other function?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, try-catch, throw

I have one doubt regarding error handling...

If a function throws an exception and that exception isn't caught in main program will crash badly.

My question is why doesn't this program crash? If an exception is thrown from `Test` function `enterNumber` will throw an exception too even though it wasn't caught?

Shouldn't every function that might throw an exception be put in a try-catch block just in case it throws it?

1°

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdexcept>

    void Test(int number) {
        if(number < 0)
            throw std::domain_error("Number is negative");
    }

    int enterNumber() {
        int number;
        std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> number;
        Test(number);           
        return number;
    }

    int main() {
        try {
            int number = enterNumber();
            std::cout << "Entered number: " << number;
        }
        catch(std::domain_error e) {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I thought it should be written like this:

2°

```
void Test(int number) {
    if(number < 0)
        throw std::domain_error("Number is negative");
}

int enterNumber() {
    int number;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    try {
        Test(number);
    }
    catch(...) {
        throw;
    }
    return number;
}

int main() {
    try {
        int number = enterNumber();
        std::cout << "Entered number: " << number;
    }
    catch(std::domain_error e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If someone could explain how the function `enterNumber` throws an exception in case `Test` throws it? (case 1°)

Thank you :)

Comment: Works as designed in C++. An uncaught function bubbles up the stack.

Comment: Exceptions are allowed to bubble up out of functions.  It is once the bubble out of main that is the problem.  If you don't bubble out of main then you're fine.

Comment: Your `try {
        Test(number);
    }
    catch(...) {
        throw;` construct is completely pointless. You catch all exceptions, only to immediately re-throw them - the same as would happen if you just removed that `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Exceptions propagate up the call stack. This is one of it's advantages, the burden to remember to propagate errors is not on the developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to catch an exception from the function that called the function that caused the exception. Indeed, best practice is to catch the exception as far as possible (but no further) from the site where the exception was thrown, as it is only at higher levels of the program that you have sufficient information to produce meaningful error messages, and/or to deal with the exception in other ways. However, the exception should be caught at *some* level of the program, or the program will terminate in an uncontrolled manner.

Comment: For some exceptions, letting them escape main and take the program down can also be perfectly fine. Sometimes it's better to crash (and write a core for later debugging) than trying to recover from a broken world and potentially causing more harm.

Comment: *"best practice is to catch the exception as far as possible from the site where the exception was thrown"* This doesn't seem right to me, it implies that catching in `main` or a thread's main function is the best place to catch exceptions. Perhaps something like "best practice is to catch the exception only where you can do something about it" or something to that effect.

Comment: @ François  I said "as far as possible" - catching and dealing with everything in main isn't often possible. I've amened the answer slightly.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I still have to disagree. This indicates that the farther you are from the throw, the better. I guess it sounds to me like you're saying you should avoid catching an exception that you could meaningfully handle if you know another catch clause is ready to handle it farther up the stack.

Comment: @François No, I didn't mean that as I don't think you should need to be aware of the catch hierarchy (if there is one) of your program. I am offering an heuristic (catch as far away as possible from throw) because experience has taught me that the vast majority of programmers catch as near as possible, eat the exception, and often thus put their program into UB land.